# Add new tab after file -> new

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a simple editor i Qt and C++. I want to have tabs, so after creating a new document, I want to open this in a new tab. My code:

```
// mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("emacs");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionExit_triggered()
{
    qApp->exit(0);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()
{
    // what to write here?
}


// main.cpp

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}


// mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionExit_triggered();
    void on_actionNew_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I have successfully managed to create an action to exit the program. But when I try something like this: `tabWidget->addTab(new QWidget(),"new tab");` is complaints that tabWidget was not declared in the scope. Anybody? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabWidget` is not a member of your `MainWindow` class, I'm guessing its an object you defined in your `ui` file, so try:

```
ui->tabWidget->addTab(...);
```

Comment: You know what, I just figured it out :) Thanks!